# Flutter Web View blank screen on Release Mode

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I have an issue where the Flutter WebView is rendering blank on the release version of my Android App on the Playstore.

Users are complaining that a page is not loading, but this page was loading very fine in debug mode.

Here is what I am doing. I am loading a local html file from my assets folder as shown in the code below:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class _InvoicePageState extends ResumableState<InvoicePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  WebViewController? _webViewController;


  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void loadPage()async{
  String html = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/html/invoice.html');
  _webViewController?.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(html ,
            mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }

  //Then in my build Method I have this
  ....
      WebView(
               onWebViewCreated:
              (WebViewController webViewController) {
               _webViewController = webViewController;
               loadPage();
                            },
                          ),
```

What could be wrong, why is it loading in debug mode but not loading in release mode?

My users are already dropping really bad reviews.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `WidgetsBinding ensureInitialized()` in your main() before runApp call?

Comment: Yes I do have ```ensureInitialized()```

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you find any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The library's official example has `InAppWebView` embedded inside `Stack` which is further embedded inside `Expanded`. That is causing the issue. Try removing the `Stack` and `Expanded` or if you really want `Stack`, then first embed `InAppWebView` inside `Expanded` and then remove the parent `Expanded`.